# Scala Future design questions

Tags: scala

I do not understand why Scala's `Future` is harder to use and has less functionality than Twitters, while the first has been created after the second. So, here are questions about `scala.concurrent.Future`:

- Why does `Future.onComplete` return `Unit` instead of `Future`? Composable methods are much more convenient.
- Why does Scala's `Future` not support cancellation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Future.onComplete` returns a unit, so the invocations cannot be chained. According to the scala docs, "note that this design is intentional, to avoid suggesting that chained invocations may imply an ordering on the execution of the registered callbacks (callbacks registered on the same future are unordered)."

To compose the future, use combinators like `flatMap`, `andThen`, and `filter`, which all return a Future.

Check out http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#functional-composition-and-for-comprehensions for more details

I think cancellation is quite nuanced. See this discussion for more details: [How to cancel Future in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009837/how-to-cancel-future-in-scala)

Comment: map is transformation and I do not want a transformation. I want to add `onSuccess` and `onFailure` handlers on returned Future

Comment: Ah sorry, good point -- I misunderstood. I updated my answer accordingly. Sounds like scala did not want the `onComplete`, `onSuccess`, and `onFailure` methods to be chainable, because that could imply an order on all chained callbacks. Sounds like a reasonable tradeoff

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987855/what-are-advantages-of-a-twitter-future-over-a-scala-future has a few more infos about the difference between the two.